# Finite state machine to detect if a number is divisible by 5 if LSB comes first

Tags: digital-logic, asic, rtl

If MSB comes in first, we can keep track of the remainder for each new bit since the additional bit will either cause the number to be 2x or 2x+1.

But if LSB comes in first, how can we come up with the fsm? I found some fsm but I wasn't able to understand how they came up with it. Can someone please explain how to go about doing this?

[image]

I was just wondering how one can come up with this fsm? I didn't really understand the description in the other post.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me

Comment: Does the source of that FSM that you show explain WHY it works?

Comment: Can you show your work so far?  See [this thread on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: We covered this [about a year ago](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/345189/11683), with answers covering both LSB-first and MSB-first.